# SQL Simple Update Statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

I have a simple table called `t_genopt` with 2 columns : `Options` and `AppliesTo`.

I get a syntax error when I run the following query:

```
UPDATE
    t_genopt
SET
    t_genopt.Option = 'trial'
WHERE
    t_genopt.AppliesTo LIKE 'VCConfigs'
```

Where is the problematic spot?

Comment: What is the column actually named: [Option] or [Options]?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the DBMS you are using, the `Option` keyword could be reserved. Quote the names which are reserved.

In SQL Server and MSAccess:

```
UPDATE
    t_genopt
SET
    [Option] = 'trial'
WHERE
    t_genopt.AppliesTo LIKE 'VCConfigs'
```

In MySQL

```
UPDATE
    t_genopt
SET
    `Option` = 'trial'
WHERE
    t_genopt.AppliesTo LIKE 'VCConfigs'
```

Comment: thanks. I get the following error: `The SELECT statement includes a reversed word or an argument name that is mispellsed or missing. or the panctuation is incorrect`

Answer (score 2):

`option` is a reserved word in many databases.  You want to escape it for this query.  The solution is likely to be either:

```
UPDATE t_genopt
SET [Option] = 'trial'
WHERE t_genopt.AppliesTo LIKE 'VCConfigs';
```

or

```
UPDATE t_genopt
SET "Option" = 'trial'
WHERE t_genopt.AppliesTo LIKE 'VCConfigs';
```

or

```
UPDATE t_genopt
SET `Option` = 'trial'
WHERE t_genopt.AppliesTo LIKE 'VCConfigs';
```

The better solution is to avoid using reserved words as column and table identifiers.

Comment: thanks. I get the following error: `The SELECT statement includes a reversed word or an argument name that is mispellsed or missing. or the panctuation is incorrect` Any ideas?

Comment: Check the documentation of the DBMS you are using to get how to quote/escape the reserved names in the queries.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @Pred, Access and SQL.

Comment: Use the `[` and `]` characters to quote the name. Also read *Damien_The_Unbeliever*'s answer

Answer (score 0):

Take out the second `t_genopt`:

```
UPDATE
    t_genopt
SET
    [Option] = 'trial'
WHERE
    t_genopt.AppliesTo LIKE 'VCConfigs'
```

Any [`UPDATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177523.aspx) statement can only affect *one* table, and the table subject to update is identified between `UPDATE` and `SET`. There's no need (and you're not allowed in most database systems) to specify the table again on the left side of assignments within the `SET` clause.

(And, as others have observed, if the column name is `Option`, as per your example, rather than `Options`, as per your narrative, you'll need to quote that use)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliver, thanks. I get the following error: `The SELECT statement includes a reversed word or an argument name that is mispellsed or missing. or the panctuation is incorrect`. Any ideas?

Comment: @user3165438 - are you using [tag:access]? (It would help if your question was tagged with which database system you're using).

Comment: @user3165438 - I've now updated my answer to use `[]` quoting, which is the style preferred for Access.